# I got an error message 'KeyError', Python, Telegram api

Tags: python, api, telegram

I am programming a chat bot for Telegram, what it does is not important. It accesses the api of Telegram and manipulates json file there.

I wanted to take care of the offset with `requests.post(url + "getUpdates?offset=" + str(update_id))`.

Whole code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests as requests
import re
import codecs
import sys

from time import sleep

UTF8Writer = codecs.getwriter('utf8')
sys.stdout = UTF8Writer(sys.stdout)

url = "https://some sort of api"

def get_chat_id(update):
    chat_id = update['message']["chat"]["id"]
    return chat_id

def get_message_text(update):
    message_text = update["message"]["text"]
    return message_text



def last_update(req):
    response = requests.get(req + "getUpdates")
    response = response.json()
    result = response["result"]
    total_updates = len(result) - 1
    return result[total_updates]

def send_message(chat_id, message_text):
    params = {"chat_id":chat_id, "text": message_text}
    response = requests.post(url + "sendMessage", data=params)
    return response

def main():
    update_id = last_update(url)["update_id"]

    while (True):
        update = last_update(url)
        message = get_message_text(update).lower()
        if update_id == update["update_id"]:
            if get_message_text(update).lower() == "Hello":
                send_message(get_chat_id(update), 'Hello World!')


            requests.post(url + "getUpdates?offset=" + str(update_id))
            update_id += 1
            sleep(1)

main()
```

Error message:

```
  File "main.py", line 450, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 413, in main
    message = get_message_text(update).lower()
  File "main.py", line 21, in get_message_text
    message_text = update["message"]["text"]
KeyError: 'text'
```

Comment: the code got simplified.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Basically this means that `update` does not have a key `text`. You can try printing `update` to see what it contains.

Comment: No worries. I suggest also reading the link I posted, it may save you many unnecessary questions in the future.

Comment: But ```update``` does contain ```text```

Comment: Pls add the output of `print(update)`

Comment: Yea I'll do that

Comment: nevermind. It seems to have been so because the update_id was the wrong one. And in the json file this entry had no text. It works again. Thanks for the link it will help me